# how to declare Explicit wait in TestNG framework where script is written for multiple browsers?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, testng, browser-automation

I am working on a selenium script where I am using explicit wait. I have a script where I have three methods to invoke IE,FireFox and Chrome browsers.

I will be executing script for one browser at a time. now the question is how should I declare the wait (explicitly). I can see two following options.
1. Create an object of WebDriverWait class Globally--- In this scenario web driver throws the exception as there is no object created for the browser class(in this case FireFoxDriver()).
2.Create an object of WebDriverWait class locally in any method-- In this scenario wait works perfectly but in case i have to use the wait again for any other element. it would ask you to create object of WebDriverWait class locally again(which is something i want to avoid)..

In Short. I just want to create object of WebDriverWait class onle once in the code. How can i do it for the below mentioned code???

following is the code..

public class para {
    WebDriver driver;

```
@BeforeClass
void InvokeFF() {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver",
            "C:/Users/Vinay/workspace_n/EGuru/drivers/geckodriver.exe");
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    // driver.get("http://seleniumpractise.blogspot.in/2016/08/bootstrap-dropdown-example-for-selenium.html");
    System.out.println("Firefox invoked");
    System.out.println("Firefox thread:" + Thread.currentThread().getId());
}

@BeforeClass(enabled = false)
void InvokeIE() {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver",
            "C:/Users/Vinay/workspace_n/EGuru/drivers/IEDriverServer.exe");
    driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
    System.out.println("Internet Explorer invoked");
    System.out.println("IE thread:" + Thread.currentThread().getId());
}

@BeforeClass(enabled = false)
void InvokeGC() {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
            "C:/Users/Vinay/workspace_n/EGuru/drivers/chromedriver.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    // driver.get("http://www.seleniumeasy.com");
    System.out.println("Chrome invoked");
    System.out.println("Chrome thread:" + Thread.currentThread().getId());

}

@Test
void Auto() throws Exception {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
    driver.get("file:///C:/Users/Vinay/Desktop/Upload1.html");
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By
            .xpath(".//*[@id='1']")));
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='1']")).click();
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Users\\Vinay\\Desktop\\AutoUpload.exe");
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is an implicit wait, not an explicit wait.  This can be accomplished by using the line of code below after your driver has been created (using whichever driver it needs)

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Obviously change the 10 seconds to whatever default timeout you want.

Comment: Implicit wait will make the script wait for 10 seconds after execution of every instruction/statement.and it can be declared only once in the script.  that would make my script slow. I want explicit wait where i want to wait whenever i required.

Comment: Please refer to http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/implicit-explicit-n-fluent-wait/ An implicit wait takes up no time if a function suceeds, it only sets a default wait time for retries.  The explicit wait is for when you need a longer wait time than the default (implicit) wait time.  Otherwise, they work pretty much the same.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to put explicitly wait please use the please code :

```
public static WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

public static void wait(String waitElement)
{
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath(waitElement)));
}
```

Worked for me !